# SSH Tunneling not working properly

Tags: ssh-tunneling, openssh

I'm trying to create a simple SSH tunnel using OpenSSH.

I have a VPS server listening on port 4444 for SSH.

From my local Ubuntu machine, I wish to create the SSH tunnel to http://edition.cnn.com/.

I use the following command:

```
ssh -L 5050:edition.cnn.com:80 x.x.x.x -p 4444
```

where `x.x.x.x` is my VPS IP.

I then press Enter, and wait a couple of seconds.

Instead of the tunnel being created, I'm logged in via SSH to my VPS.

What is wrong with my command syntax? Everywhere I look I find that I invoke it correctly.

Comment: By default `ssh` creates and connects to a remote shell or other specified command _in addition to_ any tunnels enabled with -L/D/R and -X/Y. To _not_ run the remote shell/command use `-N`. See the man page.

Answer (score 1):

Your command has setup tunnel just fine. Try connecting to `localhost:5050` and that should take you to remote host (this may not work for `vhosts` and you need local hosts entry). If you are looking to setup a generic HTTP proxy via your VPS server, take a look at this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/78351/can-i-create-ssh-to-tunnel-http-through-server-like-it-was-proxy) and use SOCKS proxy